# Notable difference in a multivariable linear approximation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, linearization

I have to use the linear approximation of $f(x, y, z) = $($5x^2$ + $y^2$)$/(z + 1)$ at $(-2, 1, 1)$ to estimate $f(-1.98, 0.97, 1.03)$

I'm getting $10.1125$, however it is a bit too low (I guess) if i compare this result with the normal substitution:  ~$10,119$

Is it really supposed to be $10.1125$ or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: A few details about what you did would helpful to check whether you're "doing something wrong."  Did you compute the gradient (vector of partial derivatives at $x_0 = (-2,1,1)$?  If so how did you use that to adjust the value of the function to approximate $f(1.98, 0.97, 1.03)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have it right.  Linearization doesn't give the exact value, it gives an approximation.

For example, if you take the parabola $y = x^2$ at $x = 2$ the slope of the tangent line is $4$, and the linear estimate of $2.03^2$ is therefore $4 + 4*.03 = 4.12$, while the exact answer is 4.1209.

Comment: I thought the difference would be smaller than 0.007, i know it's already small but i was expecting something like 0.00007

Comment: @ShinYousoro What makes you think that 0.007 is not small enough?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net i was expecting something similiar to the classic example of the square root of 4,001 (giving an 0,000000016 error). Just realized it gave me an awkward expectation.